# Тестирование аргументов переданных в Observable RxJava

Tags: java, kotlin, юнит-тесты, rxjava

Есть некий метод:

```
repository.get(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Который возвращает `Single<List<SomeObject>>`

Мне нужно протестировать, что на этот Single происходит подписка. Как протестировать подписку я знаю:

```
repository.get(arg1, arg2, arg3)
            .test()
            .assertSubscribed()
```

Но проблема этого метода в том, что он не проверяет входящие аргументы. А мне важно проверить, что происходит подписка с нужными аргументами.

Как это можно сделать?